# From the terminal, how can I delete remote GitHub branches that have served merged PRs?

Tags: git, github

**Background**: I file pull requests to an upstream repo. After those PRs are merged/closed, I want to delete the remote branches on my forked repo (origin) that served those PRs. I want to do this in one swoop from the command line.

I can do this for my *local* branches with:

```
gh pr list -A <author> -s merged --json 'headRefName' | jq -r '.[].headRefName' | tr -d '\r' | xargs git branch -d
```

I would think that this parallel code would work to delete the *remote* branches:

```
gh pr list -A <author> -s merged --json 'headRefName' | jq -r '.[].headRefName' | tr -d '\r' | xargs git push origin --delete
```

But this doesn't work. All the remote branches are still there. Here is the output I receive on the terminal:

[image: error: unable to delete 'patch-45': remote ref does not exist error: unable to delete 'patch-44': remote ref does not exist error: unable to delete 'patch-42': remote ref does not exist error: unable to delete 'patch-41': remote ref does not exist error: unable to delete 'patch-40': remote ref does not exist error: unable to delete 'patch-38': remote ref does not exist error: unable to delete 'patch-36': remote ref does not exist error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com//content.git']

And if I run this to get a list of merged remote branches:

```
gh pr list -A <author> -s merged --json 'headRefName' | jq -r '.[].headRefName' | tr -d '\r'
```

Then my output is:

[image]

Any ideas how to make it work? Thanks

**OS**: Windows 10
**Terminal**: Git Bash

Comment: Re: "I receive a few errors", can you please show the text of these errors?

Comment: Always show, do not describe, the commands run and their output please. This question is currently unclear.

Comment: @JaredBeck Done, thanks